Is all rigor mathematical in nature?
Is all rigor, mathematical rigor? Or are there other forms of rigor besides mathematical rigor? For example, is there such a thing as philosophical rigor, or scientific rigor? Personally, I think all rigor is mathematical in nature, but I would be open to any counterarguments.

@user107952 Please give your definition of "rigor". Otherwise your question has no precise answer. Thanks.

@JoWehler  Are you looking for a, er, rigorous definition?

@eigengrau I ask for the OP's definition.

@JoWehler C'mon, Jo, it's a joke, albeit a little one.

In  "The Philosophy of Quantum Mechanics", Max Jammer describes a physical theory as "a partially interpreted formal system", which is more or less mathematical. See chapter 1 for a detailed discussion. And I'd guess anything that can be formulated in a rigorous fashion can be described in more or less that same way.

@eigengrau IMO your comment goes in the direction: Rigourous theory = Mathematical formalism + interpretation. - I am sceptical that the same degree of mathematical formalism as we have in physics can be requested from other sciences too. Moreover, quantum mechanics exemplifies the case of a scientific theory with mature mathematical formalization but rather controversial interpretations.

Of course not, every special science, and even subdisciplines within them have their own norms of rigor. NIH even issued guidelines on rigor in biosciences, see Hofseth. There is "physical level of rigor" and "informal rigor" even in mathematics. Engineering fields and even theology scholars have their own forms of rigor.

I think there are many examples of rigor without mathematics. Here are a few:

Rigorous systems, rule-based but not mathematical, for describing the syntax of programming languages, like Backus-Naur form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form
Rigorous systems for describing the syntax of natural languages, e.g. binary branching syntax trees in linguistics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_structure_grammar
Rigorous systems for logical deduction. You might argue that formal logic is really mathematics, and although I don't agree, I see the point: for example, Boole's presentation of propositional logic was expressed in mathematical terms right from the outset (e.g. his 1854 "The Laws of Thought"). But take a look at Aristotle's "Prior Analytics" for rigorous rules of inference which are not expressed in a mathematical way at all.
Rigorous non-mathematical systems for metaphysics: Spinoza's "Ethics" is the famous one, but also take a look at Zalta's 1983 book "Abstract Objects," or Meixner's 1997 book "Axiomatic Formal Ontology," or for that matter, Aristotle's "Categories."


I upvoted because clearly rigor can take many guises, not all of them related to language production. But I want to probe this idea that a grammar is not-mathematical. If grammars are taken to be linear sequences with production rules that are functional in nature, isn't something like EBNF nothing more than applied mathematical systems? Don't they have an algebraic semantics? And if a formalism can be grounded in an algebraic semantics, on what basis is not mathematical?

I guess I ask because Linz's text on Formal Language and Automata consists of an entire textbook built of definitions that expressed in set-theoretic and functional notation (not to mention the representations are literally graph-theoretic. In fact, despite that its a topic in computer science pedagogy, the course is essentially an exercise in mathematical notation.

You've selected a good answer, because there are many forms of rigor. Even doing pushups can be done rigorously, so the notion of rigor is quite fluid depending on the context in which the term is used. Certainly, a rigorous police investigation isn't very mathematical, and even in philosophy, a rigorous exposition of a topic can be done without formalisms of any sort, a fact analytical philosophers sometimes forget.
But you are speaking generally of intellectual rigor, this idea that mathematical rigor cleaves to and from. Euclid was rigorous, of course. But so was Spinoza. So was Kant, and neither of those men had much to contribute in the way of mathematics, because each was a philosopher using natural language. From the WP article:

Rigour (British English) or rigor (American English; see spelling differences) describes a condition of stiffness or strictness.1 These constraints may be environmentally imposed, such as "the rigours of famine"; logically imposed, such as mathematical proofs which must maintain consistent answers; or socially imposed, such as the process of defining ethics and law.

What I suspect you are noticing however, is that intellectual rigor is conducted, not by mathematical thinking per se, but the use of language. For instance, Microsoft's terms and conditions for Windows 11 are legally rigorous (again without mathematics or formalism) because they are in some sense linguistically thorough. And Kant is rigorous because of the number of works and the scope of his interests and terminology. Thus, in some way, the volume and diversity of language is what makes rigor what it is.
And therefore the better answer is not that all rigor is mathematical, but all mathematical rigor is linguistic. And the obviousness of that outside of the community of mathematics derives from the fact that rigor in this intellectual sense is the opposite of vagueness, ambiguity (SEP), and generality. Thus, when we are more descriptive, vagueness falls away. And when we are more explicit ambiguity falls away, and when are more specific generality falls away. And all of those efforts are done in language. The formal systems of mathematics, of course, give us the most bang for our buck, but they are not the only way to be intellectually rigorous.
